# javascript/jquery parsing json in same order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json object.

```
var json1 = {"00" : "00", "15" : "15", "30" : "30", "45" : "45"};
```

I am preparing a select element parsing the above json as follows.

```
var selElem = $('<select>', {'name' : name, 'grp' : grp});
for(key in json1)
    selElem.append($('<option>', {value:key, text: json1 [key]}));
```

but the select element created is as follows.

```
<select>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
</select>
```

The problem here is the json1 object contains 00 as 1st element but in the select element it is created at last.

Any work around or solution for this problem.

Comment: workaround yes, solution, no, JSON doesn't guarantee order http://www.json.org/ says `An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to preserve order, use an array:

```
var json1 = [{val:"00",txt:"00"}, 
             {val:"15",txt:"15"}, 
             {val:"30",txt:"30"}, 
             {val:"45",txt:"45"}];
```

And loop it:

```
var selElem = $('<select>', {'name' : name, 'grp' : grp});
for(var i=0;i<json1.length;(i+=1)){
    selElem.append($('<option>', {value:json1[i].val, text: json1[i].txt})); 
}
```

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/6gb5E/)

Comment: Your solution is nice ... But `json1[i].val` and `json1[i].txt` are returning undefined...

Comment: You probably didn't update your json source, fundamentally that is the problem... object property enemeration isn't NEC in order the property was first defined

Comment: @Sandeep: added a jsfiddle link to my answer